# Cannot configure double-click (to open a folder) in files

Tags: pantheon-files, mouse, files, release-odin

Running the Odin beta 2 release. I referred to some past answers but could not find the right setting to configure double-click to open a folder in Files.

```
 gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences single-click false
No such key “single-click”
```

I tried the dconf-editor too, the *single-click* setting couldn't be found inside the files menu:
[image: dconf screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odin no longer supports a choice of single-click/double-click modes I am afraid. There is just one "mixed" mode where single clicking on a folder icon navigates and clicking on a file icon selects. There are still several ways to select a folder:

- Click on the helper emblem
- Hold down Shift or Control key and click
- Click on white space and drag to rubberband select
- (In List View) click on the Size, Type or Modified column

Comment: The decision to remove the double-click mode seems to be final, see [this comment](https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/222#issuecomment-890063151) by Cassidy James. There really doesn't seem to be any way of changing this, except for forking Files.

Comment: This situation really sucks... I miss double click